# Getting the real width with $(this).scrollWidth is very slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll

I am doing the fallowing

```
$('.Row .Cell .Text').each(function (index, item) {
                if (this.scrollWidth > $(this).parent().width())
                    $(this).next().show();

                else $(this).next().hide();
});
```

all is fine when i dont have allot of $('.Row .Cell .Text'). but if i have allot of rows and cells, the code above and in particular

```
this.scrollWidth
```

takes allot of time.

Any idea how i can get the same thing but faster?

added a fiddle [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ovi123/nYSDy/)

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Can you post it?

Comment: please create a demo jsfiddle

Comment: @Ovi I see no problem here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mRnDC/2/ it runs in about 150ms for me...

Comment: @Mortalus  i created a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ovi123/nYSDy/). this is how my html looks. it takes 2143ms but for me it takes longer, not sure y. is there any thing wrong with tho code there?

Comment: @Floradu88 i added a fiddle see  comment above

Comment: @Mortalus I agree with you: 120ms to load on bad internet connection.

Comment: @Ovi what your code should actually do?

Comment: @Ovi having a look at your example you are trying to iterate trough 5640 DOM elements and calculate their scroll width each time .. this might take a while ... sorry ... if you describe your final goal we might help with alternatives ... here is a more detailed fiddle with an average iteration time and element count http://jsfiddle.net/nYSDy/2/

Comment: The fiddle is too contrived to demonstrate what you're actually trying to do, and therefore figure out whether any alternative is the correct answer.  Your code is _probably_ causing the layout engine to re-layout the page for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to hide `.Icon` of the if `.Text` width > `.Cell`. See below approach,

I tried to move jQuery code out side looping by using a `filter`.

**CSS**

```
/*set overflow for .Text - This lets you calculate the actual width of .Text*/
.Text { overflow: hidden; } 

/* Hide .Icon by default and show only if .Text width < .Cell width*/
.Cell .Icon { display: none; }
```

**JS**

```
$('.Row .Cell .Text').filter(function (i, el) {    
    return el.scrollWidth <= this.parentNode.scrollWidth; //Thanks @nicoabie
}).next().show();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nYSDy/4/

Comment: WOOOW! Thank you very much! you defiantly win the prize! you answer did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though the bulk of the performance hit is actually coming from this:

$(this).next().hide();

At first I thought you might be taking a performance hit because of how jquery may handle the extra text nodes created by spaces between your elements so I tried:

this.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';

This didn't really help matters, so it seems simply setting the style on this many elements is extremely slow.  To get around this you may consider setting the default style to what you expect to be the most common case and then only reacting to the other case.  For the fiddle example you posted this would result in:

CSS:

```
.Icons {
  display: none;
}
```

New JS:

```
$('.Row .Cell .Text').each(function (index, item) {
                if (this.scrollWidth > $(this).parent().width())
                    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Addendum:
it turns out that adding a class to all of these elements is a little bit faster so you could do this http://jsfiddle.net/XuhaT/1/ :

CSS:

```
#vTable {
    width:800px;
}
.Icon {
    display: none;
}
.visible.Icon {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#countOfItems").html($('#vTable .Row ').length);
var startDate = new Date();
$('.Row .Cell .Text ').each(function (index, item) {
    if (this.scrollWidth > $(this).parent().width()) $(this).next().addClass('visible');
});
var endDate = new Date();

$("#claculationTime").html(endDate - startDate);
```

Comment: Thank you! your solution helped make performance batter. do you have any more ideas for making it even better? if i dont get any better answer i will accept yours.

Comment: You can upgrade jquery to 1.9.1.  There are some optimizations there that will slightly improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up Brandon's answer approximately 6 times using this comparator

```
if (this.scrollWidth > this.parentNode.scrollWidth)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, it made it a little faster. I know in the jsFilddle it is allot faster but in my application its only a little faster.

Comment: You are welcome @Ovi, have you tried or maybe it is possible not to do all the processing at once but every time the user scrolls? Also I think this is a good opportunity to take advantage of web workers, have you seen paralleljs?

Comment: How do i do it every time the user scrolls? sounds like a good idea. What are web workers?